# Why am I getting "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota" error, when I have plenty of quotas?

Tags: youtube-api

Why am I getting "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota" error, when I have plenty of quotas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I admit that the UI is pretty bad concerning the quota but you are running out of quota as 96% of your daily quota has been consumed.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Yes, it is coming to an end for today, but not 100%. I assume that the cost of this operation overlaps the limit, so it doesn't let me perform it. Am I right? Ok, I will try tomorrow, we'll see how it goes. Will update tomorrow. Thanks.